# Does JavaScript's JSON.Parse() function have a max string length limit for the parameter it accepts?

Tags: javascript, json

Does JavaScript's `JSON.Parse()` have a max string length limit for the parameter it accepts? If I pass a string to `JSON.Parse()` that exceeds the specific length, will it through an exception or decline from returning a valid value?

Please provide an answer supported from valid resources.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what is with all these tags? Why `asp.net`, `parameters`, `asp.net-mvc-5`?

Answer (score 2):

There's no inherant size limits on JSON, but there can be limitations set by the browser or the server sending / handling related requests. For example, ASP.net has [`JavaScriptSerializer.MaxJsonLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_Script_Serialization_JavaScriptSerializer_MaxJsonLength) which can limit the length (defaults to *2097152*)

This takes an 32-bit interger, and so is limited to *2147483644* characters

> Int32
>
> The maximum length of JSON strings. The default is 2097152 characters, which is equivalent to 4 MB of Unicode string data.